# I am trying to pull the value based on the key in a NSArray in Objective-C that are passed in a URL. How do I get the value form the key?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am pulling in the components from a `NSURL` using `componentswithurl:` `resolvingagainstbaseurl:`. This gives me an `NSArray` of query items, but I cannot get the value for each object out of the array based on the key. I am doing this for a custom url that is launching my app from another app. I am doing something like:

Incoming url: `something://init?item1=xxxx&item2=yyy&item3=www2&item4=sss`

```
NSURLComponents *comp = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:true];
NSAray *compDict = comp.queryItems;
```

Thus giving me a list of object with a key value pair.

```
compDict[0] =
    name = item1
    value = xxxx
```

and so on. I am trying to get the value based on the name(key) using:

`NSString *value = [compDict valueForKey:@"item1"];`

but this gives me an error `- [<NSURLQueryItem> valueforundefinedkey:]this class is not key value coding-compliant for key item1`.

Can someone help me out on this.

Comment: `compDict` is not a `Dictionary`, it's an array of `NSURLQueryItem`. Iterate on it, and get its `name` and `value` property: for `(NSULRQueryItem *aQueryItetm in compDict) { NSLog(@"Key: %@ - Value: %@", [aQueryItem key], [aQueryItem value]); }`

Comment: [aQueryItem key] terminated with an uncaught exception. 'NSInvalidArgumentException' , reason: '-[NSURLQueryItem key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Comment: Sorry, it's `[aQueryItem name]`, since the property in `NSURLQueryItem` is `name`, not `key`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlqueryitem?language=objc

Comment: Excellent. Name fixed the issue. Thank you.